# Painting JComponent as a long task

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, paintcomponent, swingworker

1. All interactions with Swing JComponent must be done in Event Dispatch Thread. Painting too.
2. Long task must be run outside Event Dispatch Thread, otherwise they will block GUI.

But what if long task is painting application in Graphics2D for example 1000 times? Is this conflicting requirements?

```
public class MyObject extends JPanel {
    ...
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {...}
    ...
}
```

If I need to call this method so much times, that it can be considered as a long task, what should I do, to avoid blocking GUI? As far as I understand it is not allowed just delegate it in SwingWorker. It there any workaround for such "long tasks"?

Comment: Can you explain why does it take so much time? Does it access a database? Does it invoke a long-running transaction?
Another question: Why does it run 1000 times? How much time do you have for that 1000 paint?

Comment: Calculate all your numbers and Shapes outside the paintComponent method, so all the paintComponent method needs to do is, well, paint.  Just drawing a thousand objects is unlikely to affect performance, especially on a machine with a modern video card.

Comment: @Tamas Rev Yes, actually i painting my appllication 10.000+ times to generate pdfs (just call paintComponent with pdf-g2). And i want to show a progress bar while doing that.

Comment: `painting my appllication 10.000+ times to generate pdfs` - makes no sense to me. Why are you repainting 10K times to generate a PDF. Are you doing animation? The user will never notice 10K incremental changes in a PDF. If you are generating 10K PDFs, then what does Swing have to do with this? I would guess the PDF is generated and saved in the background. If all you want to do is update a progress bar there is no need for custom painting. Read the tutorial on [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for a working example.

Comment: @camickr actually i am making personolized blanks for a large user base. Please do not use "scarecrow" so aggresive and obvious. Painting application 10k+ times may sound strange, but still a possible task.

Comment: @AvrDragon `actually i am making personolized blanks for a large user base.` - so it sounds like a background task that is running and you just update a progress bar showing how many "blanks" have been created. If there a need to display 10k blanks on the screen. Will a user be staring at the screen looking at all 10k blanks as they are created? Are these blanks saved to an image? Its the work flow I'm trying to understand not the fact that 10k of something is created. Based on your description I really don't see why you are worried about the EDT.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an exception. As long as you're not painting to the screen, then you can invoke it in a background thread. The point is that the actual UI stuff should happen on the event-dispatch thread so all the changes will be visible for the user.

This is a skeleton for how this should happen:

```
public class MyObject extends JPanel {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_PDFS = 10_000;

    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, NUMBER_OF_PDFS);

    public void paintPdfs() {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); // this can come somewhere else too
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PDFS; i++) {
            final int newProgressBarValue = i; // you might need some mapping, depends on the setup of the taskbar
            threadPool.execute(() -> {
                try {
                    Graphics pdfG2 = getPdfGraphics();
                    MyObject.this.paintComponent(pdfG2);
                } finally {
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
                        int progressBarValue = progressBar.getValue();
                        if (progressBarValue < newProgressBarValue) {
                            progressBar.setValue(newProgressBarValue);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private Graphics getPdfGraphics() {
        // I don't know how to do this. On the other hand, you do :)
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I can see only one caveat: the swing objects should not change during this print. If they do, then you need another trick. This other trick would be printing the pdfs in the event-dispatch thread one-by-one:

```
public void paintPdfs() {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_PDFS; i++) {
        final int newProgressBarValue = i; // you might need some mapping, depends on the setup of the taskbar
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                Graphics pdfG2 = getPdfGraphics();
                MyObject.this.paintComponent(pdfG2);
            } finally {
                int progressBarValue = progressBar.getValue();
                if (progressBarValue < newProgressBarValue) {
                    progressBar.setValue(newProgressBarValue);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This second approach runs one `paintComponent()` at a time, so it won't freeze your UI. This is why it doesn't need any executor or worker thread. It just makes sure that it adds

Comment: First `paintComponent` should never be `public`, it's `protected` for a reasons, there should never be a need to call it directly, instead, you should be using `print` or `printAll` which are designed for this kind of operation, disabling double buffering for one